# Ruby create JSON from SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, ruby

I am trying to create JSON in Ruby from data coming from a SQL Server table, based off a query. I've worked with Ruby quite a bit and JSON some.  But never together.

This is a sample of the JSON I'm trying to create.

Even help with just creating the JSON with the nested arrays and the root element would be helpful.

```
{
  "aaSequences": [
    {
     "authorIds": [
        "ent_fdfdfdfdf_one"
      ],
      "aminoAcids": "aminoAcids_data",
      "name": "bbbbb-22",
      "schemaId": "ls_jgjgjg",
      "registryId": "src_fgfgfgf",
      "namingStrategy": "NEW_IDS"
    },
    {
     "authorIds": [
        "ent_fdfdfdfdf_two"
      ],
      "aminoAcids": "aminoAcids_data",
      "name": "bbbbb-22",
      "schemaId": "ls_jgjgjg",
      "registryId": "src_fgfgfgf",
      "namingStrategy": "NEW_IDS"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the T-SQL JSON functions to return your result set already in JSON format?

Comment: Yes I’ve tried a lot with the sql functions.  I was getting stuck on how to format it correctly and creating the nested arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Generate a JSON from a Ruby hash object

To generate a json, first start with a hash (like a dict) in Ruby

`my_hash = {:foo => 1, :bar => 2, :baz => 3}`

Make sure you require the json package as well

`require 'json'`

Then you can simply convert the hash object to a JSON string

`my_hash.to_json        #  outputs: "{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3'}"`

You can nest arrays into your hash as well

`my_hash_2 = {:foo => [1, 2, 3, 4], :bar => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}`

I'll let you try that one on your own, but ruby will handle the nested object just fine for you.

[From the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

Comment: Okay I think I have it...  

`
require 'json'

my_hash_3 = {:aaSequences => [
{
:authorIds => [
'ent_fdfdfdfdf_one'
],
:aminoAcids => 'aminoAcids_data',
:name => 'bbbbb-22',
:schemaId => 'ls_jgjgjg',
:registryId => 'src_fgfgfgf',
:namingStrategy => 'NEW_IDS'
 }
 ]
}

output2 = JSON.pretty_generate(my_hash_3)     

File.open("temp4.json","w") do |f|
 f.write(output2)
end
`

Comment: thank you,   now I need to connect to SQL Server run a query and assign the hash values from the SQL Server fields in a for loop.    Ive used tiny_tds before...is this the best gem now for this?  Also what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I ended up just using tinytds and throwing the values into a hash and then throwing those into the JSON hash...works great...   Thank you for your help................................................

`
jsonFileOutput0 = {:aaSequences => [{:authorIds => ["#{authorIds}"],:aminoAcids => "#{aminoAcids}",:name => "#{name}",:schemaId => "#{schemaId}",:registryId => "#{registryId}",:namingStrategy => "#{namingStrategy}"}]}
`

Comment: how would I add a comma between each record, in the JSON file?
Do I need to append to the bottom of the file and insert the comma each time?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your file layout is like, but if you have a list of all your jsons do this: `joined = all_jsons.join("\n,\n")`. Then write `all_jsons` to the file.