# Creating json with RUBY looping through SQL Server table

Tags: json, sql-server, ruby

This is a followup to this question:

[Ruby create JSON from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654109/ruby-create-json-from-sql-server)

I was able to create nested arrays in JSON.  But I'm struggling with looping through records and appending a file with each record.  Also how would I add a root element just at the top of the json and not on each record. "aaSequences" needs to be at the top just once... I also need a comma between each record.

here is my code so far

```
require 'pp'
require 'tiny_tds'
require 'awesome_print'
require 'json'

class Document
    def initialize strategy
        @document = strategy

    #load helper functions
    load "helpers_ruby.rb"

    #set environment 'dev', 'qa', or 'production'
    load "envconfig_ruby.rb"
    
    end

    def StartUP
        @document.StartUP
    end

    def getseqrecord
        @document.getseqrecord
    end


end

class GetSqlaaSequence

  def StartUP
    ##system "clear"    ##linux
    system "cls"        ##Windows   

        # create connection to db

    $connReportingDB = createReportingxxSqlConn($ms_sql_host, $ms_sql_user, $ms_sql_password, $ms_sql_dbname)

    ##$currentDateTime = DateTime.now
    ##pp 'def StartUP ran at: '+$currentDateTime.to_s

  end


    def getseqrecord

  
        # get the aaaaSequences data
        @result = $connReportingDB.execute("SELECT 
        [jsonFile]
      ,[id]
      ,[title]
      ,[authorIds]
      ,[name]
      ,[aminoAcids]
      ,[schemaId]
      ,[registryId]
      ,[namingStrategy] 
      FROM tablename      
      ")
    
        $aaSequences = Array.new
        @i = 0

        @result.each do |aaSequence|

    jsonFile = aaSequence['jsonFile']
    id = aaSequence['id']
    title = aaSequence['title']
    authorIds = aaSequence['authorIds']
    name = aaSequence['name']
    aminoAcids = aaSequence['aminoAcids']
    schemaId = aaSequence['schemaId']
    registryId = aaSequence['registryId']
    namingStrategy = aaSequence['namingStrategy']
      
            ##end

            @hash = Hash[
                "jsonFile", jsonFile,
                "id", id,
                "title", title,
                "authorIds", authorIds,
                "name", name,
                "aminoAcids", aminoAcids,
                "schemaId", schemaId,
                "registryId", registryId,
                "namingStrategy", namingStrategy
                    ]
                    
            @filename = jsonFile


jsonFileOutput0 = {:"#{title}" => [{:authorIds => ["#{authorIds}"],:aminoAcids => "#{aminoAcids}",:name => "#{name}",:schemaId => "#{schemaId}",:registryId => "#{registryId}",:namingStrategy => "#{namingStrategy}"}]}

                        
jsonFileOutput = JSON.pretty_generate(jsonFileOutput0)     


File.open(jsonFile,"a") do |f|
  f.write(jsonFileOutput)

####ad the comma between records...Not sure if this is the best way to do it...
# File.open(jsonFile,"a") do |f|
  # f.write(',')  
 # end
 
end


            
            $aaSequences[@i] = @hash                    
            @i = @i + 1
            
            
        ##@createReportingSqlConn.close 
            end
        
        end     
    end

Document.new(GetSqlaaSequence.new).StartUP
  
#get aaSequences and create json files
Document.new(GetSqlaaSequence.new).getseqrecord
```

here is a sample of the json it creates so far...

```
{
  "aaSequences": [
    {
      "authorIds": [
        "fff_fdfdfdfd"
      ],
      "aminoAcids": "aminoAcids_data",
      "name": "fdfdfddf-555_1",
      "schemaId": "5555fdfd5",
      "registryId": "5fdfdfdf",
      "namingStrategy": "NEW_IDS"
    }
  ]
}{
  "aaSequences": [
    {
      "authorIds": [
        "fff_fdfdfdfd"
      ],
      "aminoAcids": "aminoAcids_data",
      "name": "fdfdfddf-555_2",
      "schemaId": "5555fdfd5",
      "registryId": "5fdfdfdf",
      "namingStrategy": "NEW_IDS"
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is an example of what I need it to look like

```
{
  "aaSequences": [
    {
     "authorIds": [
        "authorIds_data"
      ],
      "aminoAcids": "aminoAcids_data",
      "name": "name_data",
      "schemaId": "schemaId_data",
      "registryId": "registryId_data",
      "namingStrategy": "namingStrategy_data"
    },
    {
     "authorIds": [
        "authorIds_data"
      ],
      "aminoAcids": "aminoAcids_data",
      "name": "name_data",
      "schemaId": "schemaId_data",
      "registryId": "registryId_data",
      "namingStrategy": "namingStrategy_data"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using SQL Server for this? You could do this pretty simply with `FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('aaSequences')` at the end of your `SELECT` query. Sample data would help

Comment: I will try FOR JSON in sql again.  But I couldn’t figure out how to build the format with the nested arrays.

Comment: I feel like I’m very close with ruby.  I just cant figure out how you add a root element to the data then the rest of the data.  

This is part of a larger integration and I wrote a lot of it in ruby

Comment: Oh btw I provided the sample data json in the question text.

Comment: < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814217/create-nested-json-arrays-using-for-json-path>

I found this.  I will try this

Comment: We need sample *input* data, preferably `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements. Arrays are a bit annoying in SQL Server, because there is no `JSON_AGG` function: the usual answer is to use `STRING_AGG` instead. You probably need something like `SELECT authorIds, aminoAcids, name, schemaId, registryId, namingStrategy FROM tablename FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('aaSequences')` but it's unclear how `authorIds` fits in, can't say without seeing your input data

Comment: I'm using a view off a table for the query.  Insert statements??  Why would you need those?  I'm not inserting anything back to sql?  
here is the view:
CREATE VIEW vw_aaSequences
AS SELECT 'createBulkAASeq_' + seq_id + '.json' AS jsonFile, seq_id AS [id], 'aaSequences' AS title, 'ent_LaFp3bgw' AS authorIds, 'AAORF00' + CAST(id AS varchar) + SUBSTRING(seq_id, 6, 4) AS [name], [seq] AS aminoAcids, 'ts_3Hvv84dU' AS schemaId, 'src_abswnJB0' AS registryId, 'NEW_IDS' AS namingStrategy
   FROM [GeneralDB17].[dbo].[FosmidFAA_Raw0]

Comment: This works so far...  I just need to nest the authorids array...

SELECT [authorIds], [aminoAcids], [name], [schemaId], [registryId], [namingStrategy]
FROM [dbo].[vw_aaSequences] FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('aaSequences')

Comment: I'm not sure why this is an array [authorIds]...this is data I am posting to a 3rd party cloud app and that is their required format.  My guess is the [authorIds] is a list vs a reg field.

Comment: We need `INSERT` statements so we can construct a https://dbfiddle.uk to replicate your scenario. Apart from the method I noted above for `authorIds` another method if you only have a single value to putin the array is `JSON_MODIFY('[]', 'append $', authorIds) AS authorIds` which will return `["someAuthorid"]` as part of your JSON. See eg https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=31edd74ad132d4f42011aee9a35f1d6f

Comment: here you go

................

INSERT INTO [dbo].[aaSequences]( [authorIds], [aminoAcids], [name], [schemaId], [registryId], [namingStrategy] )
VALUES( 'authorIds_data', 'aminoAcids_data', 'name_data', 'schemaId_data', 'registryId_data', 'namingStrategy_data' );

Comment: hey this works the json looks correct..........

Comment: OK so what's wrong with what I said? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=558473790840760ef121c262e89183e1

Comment: SELECT JSON_MODIFY('[]', 'append $', authorIds) AS authorIds, 'aminoAcids_data'[aminoAcids], [name], [schemaId], [registryId], [namingStrategy]
FROM [dbo].[vw_aaSequences] FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('aaSequences')

Comment: nothing is wrong

Comment: this works
SELECT JSON_MODIFY('[]', 'append $', authorIds) AS authorIds, 'aminoAcids_data'[aminoAcids], [name], [schemaId], [registryId], [namingStrategy]
FROM [dbo].[vw_aaSequences] FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('aaSequences')

Comment: this is awesome thanks

Comment: instead of adding a comment reply as answer and I will accept as answer...the sql method is creates the json exactly as needed...Thank you soo much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do the whole thing in SQL using `FOR JSON`.

Unfortunately, arrays are not possible using this method. There are anumber of hacks, but the easiest one in your situation is to just append to `[]` using `JSON_MODIFY`

```sql
SELECT
  authorIds = JSON_MODIFY('[]', 'append $', a.authorIds),
  [aminoAcids],
  [name],
  [schemaId],
  [registryId],
  [namingStrategy]
FROM aaSequences a
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('aaSequences');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=558473790840760ef121c262e89183e1)

Comment: Any chance you would you know how I create json like this with the for JSON?

{
 "assayResults": [
  {
   "fields": {
    "entity": "dfdfdfd",
    "fosmid": "gfhfghfghf",
    "gc_content": "444",
    "gene_end": "444",
    "gene_id": "7",
    "gene_start": "4",
    "gene_type": "fsdfsf",
    "length": "4343",
    "strand": "-"
   },
   "schemaId": "fdfdfdfdf"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: this is what I tried...

 SELECT top 1 JSON_MODIFY('{'+[entity]+[fosmid]+[gc_content]+[gene_end]+[gene_id]+ [gene_start]+[gene_type]+[length]+[strand]+'}', 'append $', [fields]) as [fields], [schemaId]
FROM tablename
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('assayResults')

Comment: should I add as a new question?

Comment: oh wait i figured it out...image that...using the docs.Microsoft websites works sometimes, lol    
SELECT TOP 1 entity AS 'fields.entity', fosmid AS 'fields.fosmid', gc_content AS 'fields.gc_content', gene_end AS 'fields.gene_end', gene_id AS 'fields.gene_id', gene_start AS 'fields.gene_start', gene_type AS 'fields.gene_type', [length] AS 'fields.length', strand AS 'fields.strand', schemaId
FROM tablename
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('assayResults');

Comment: You could also nest `fields` in a subquery also with `FOR JSON`